# Are the results of Fizeau type experiments better explained by relativistic velocity addition or by the relativistic doppler effect

Tags: special-relativity

Are the results of Fizeau type experiments better explained by relativistic velocity addition or by the relativistic doppler effect. Or do both approaches give the same answer?

Answer (score 1):

The arguments from velocity addition and from Doppler effect are both important, because in physics we are aiming for a coherent set of ideas, so it is very valuable to tackle a given phenomenon from more than one point of view in order to check things out and see if the ideas are mutually consistent. The Fizeau experiments were historically very important to Einstein as he developed his thinking about relativity (more important than Michelson-Morley experiment, for example). At that time it was not yet clear what is and is not true about the speed of light. The speed of light in water is less than $c$ and it can and does vary from one inertial reference frame to another.